# How to split a list into two sublists with almost equal means?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with observations and want to split it into two equal sized lists, which would have their means as close as possible to each other.

I understand that this could be done by taking all possible combinations and choosing the one that gives the least mean deviation, but do there exist any more effective ways of doing that? Perhaps not yielding an ideal pair, but close to it.

Comment: Sort the list and then start assigning values to each list by alternating the lowest and highest values. For more details, you'll have to provide a [mcve] as explained in the previous comment.

Comment: In this kind of an example, I think you would also like to keep the standard deviation similar

Comment: @pault thanks! I just needed an idea

Answer (score 3):

Since the sublists are of equal length, giving them the same mean is equivalent to giving them the same sum, which must be half the sum of the original list. Or, in the approximate case, it must be as close as possible to half the sum of the original list.

This is a variation of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). It is an "NP hard" problem, meaning there is no known efficient algorithm which gives an optimal solution, but there are [several heuristics which give approximate answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Approximation_algorithm_approaches). You may be able to adapt one of these heuristics to the case where the two sublists must have equal length.

Comment: The partition problem is hard because the subsets are not the required to be the same size. If they're the same size, it becomes simple, @pault's comment is probably correct.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: "The restriction of requiring the partition to have equal size, or that all input integers be distinct, is also NP-hard."

Comment: @pault's comment seems to describe a greedy algorithm, but not specifically enough for me to interpret concretely. If you can provide a concrete-enough implementation of his idea, I'd be happy to take a look at it; but I highly doubt a one-pass greedy algorithm will be able to solve this problem optimally.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's not as simple as @pault suggsted. Input `[1, 2, 10, 100, 105, 200]` I think the solution is `[1, 10, 200] [2, 100, 105]` (sums are 211 and 207). This doesn't seem to come from any kind of alternating highest/lowest.

Comment: My comment doesn't guarantee the optimal split. It was just a suggestion since OP said *"Perhaps not yielding an ideal pair, but close to it."* I would probably recommend a snaking assignment algorithm (like a fantasy sports draft) which in @Barmar's example would result in `[1, 100, 105], [2, 10, 200]` (sums are 206 and 212). Not the best solution, but close and easy to implement. There may be a degenerate case that would break this method, but I think on average it would yield reasonable results.